# Best practice for sending/receiving multiple HTTP request in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have ASP.NET application need send multiple HTTP request to different endpoint and merge the responses from all endpoints for subsequent processing.

My current solution is like this:

1. Create request list to put all request

   ```
   var requests = new List<Request>() {...}
   ```
2. Create tasks for each request

   ```
   var tasks = requests.ToDictionary(
           request => request, request => function(request, cts.Token));
   ```

   The delegate function simply send and receive the response for each request:

   ```
   async Task<Response> HandleRequest(Request request, CancellationToken ct)
   {
   ...
       await httpClient.PostAsync(...)
   ...
   }
   ```
3. Wait when all task compleate

   ```
   await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Values);
   ```

This approach works, but seems not really parallel, I wonder whether there is better solution could give me better parallelism which result in better performance?

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Not yet, I am now still using the Task.WhenAll approach.